# Launch MSWord without checking templates

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have Word 2010 set up with a bunch of templates located on a network drive. When I'm out of the office, starting Word is delayed as it looks for those network files.
Is there a way to stop this without removing all the templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can find, there is not a way to do that without removing the template. Because it is linked, it will look for the template every time.

To improve opening time, you might try turning off the automatic updates for the template. Can't guarantee it will help, but worth a try.

> File > Options > Add-Ins > Manage: (at the bottom), select Templates,
>   then click <kbd>Go</kbd>

[image]